# Background image PCL xamarin forms iOS zoomed in

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working on a PCL project in Xamarin forms and started working on the iOS implementation because I finished the Android one. The problem I'm having is that the background image of my views are zoomed in (as are the icons on the toolbar).It's probably using the full sized image so I'd expect to use something like `Aspect=Aspect.AspectFit` but since I'm using PCL code I used `Background= Height>Width ? <picture_string_portrait> : <picture_string_landscape>`, which expects a string. I can't seem to figure out how to fix this +I can only share default code since this is for a company I'm currently working for (so no screenies aswell I'm afraid).

This is a part of my pcl code (myview.xaml.cs) which hits on load and on orientationchange. In Android it scales nicely but in iOS it doesn't.

```
private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{

     BackgroundImage = Height > Width ? "background_portrait.jpg" : "background_landscape.jpg";

 }
```

If this is a noob question I apologize but I've done my fair share of googling and can't seem to find anything usefull. A PCL solution that works for all would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason one is a JPG and the other a PNG? I'd expect them to be the same. Maybe you made a typo which is why one isn't loading?

Comment: It was a typo when adding "default" code instead of "work" code. I'm changing it , thanks for noticing mb! The pictures are showing perfectly but they are just zoomed in like its showing the actual size of the picture but it just doensn't fit the screen so it only shows a part of the top left corner as the full background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `ContentPage.BackgroundImage` is that you can't control it's aspect ratio. Seeing as how devices come in all sizes and shapes an alternate solution might work better for you. You could achieve the same result by using an `Image` inside the `ContentPage` and playing around with its `Aspect`. One way would be with an `AbsoluteLayout` like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Sample">
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" Source="background.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">
            // Content
        </StackLayout>                   
    </AbsoluteLayout>             
</ContentPage>
```

Another would be with a `RelativeLayout` like in this sample:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.nl/2015/02/using-full-size-none-stretched.html

Comment: Hi Steven, thank you for providing me another solution! I assume for the screen rotation handling I can just give a name to the image and address it  in my screen rotation code and provide the portrait/landscape picture? Anyways this answer will aid me to achieve what I wanted, cheers!